# How to mute an annoying player who keeps pinging in League of Legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

I can mute a player's chat by clicking on the `speaker icon` in the score board. Though I will still get his/her pings.

How can I mute the player's pings too?

Comment: If possible, can you please check the answers once again? A new patch made it so 2 of them are no longer true (including the accepted version)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With patch 7.10 Riot has introduced an option to [**mute player pings**](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/patch/patch-710-notes#patch-ping-muting).

> The new ping-mute button axes standard pings, smart pings, and the newer HUD pings. The old mute-chat button is still there, and still mutes chat as well as extracurricular animations (/d) and emotes (ctrl+6).

You can find the ping-mute button on the in-game scoreboard right next to the old mute button.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

As far as I remember, you can't mute pings.

Comment: Nope you can't. You can lower the sound in the in-game settings tho

Comment: So sad to know...

Comment: Pings were meant to be used as some sort of instant communication, then mics were introduced and pings were still there as an alternative. 

The problem is that people tend to abuse the pings and it just gets annoying, sometimes intentionally.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately they haven't implemented a way for you to cancel out the pings in game.

I believe this was due to them not wanting people to miss out on important information that comes with them (Eventually they will get a cooldown on their pings when spammed)

You can adjust the volume for these pings however in your options>Sound 
However that will effect every player in the game.

This has been a requested feature from a fair number of players however I believe they might be hesitant to include it.

Comment: So sad to know...